# How to create a simple 3d sphere for cocos3d using blender and PowerVR SDK

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, cocos3d

I am a fresher in cocos3d. I want to create a simple project - a 3d sphere rotating. i have designed a 3d sphere using blender. So i want help in creating collada file and pod file. What all are the things should be taken care while creating this simple 3d object using blender and PowerVR SDK. Thanks

Comment: Check these links, http://brenwill.com/cocos3d/  and http://brenwill.com/2011/cocos3d-importing-converting-collada-to-pod/  It has all the information about it. This is alone enough. I use blender for creating blend file and convert to dae and use PVRGeoPODGUI for converting as POD to use in Cocos3d project. I would also suggest use their cocos3d forum from http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org for any queries to get quick solutions.

Answer (score 0):

How about you make the simple sphere in blender, and then export it using Jeff LaMarche's [Blender-to-iOS script](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.sg/2011/04/blender-257-objective-c-export-script.html)? This wouldn't even require Cocos or PowerVR, but it's a good start. Since you can integrate Cocos with non-Cocos classes easily in iOS it might be helpful. You could go further and leverage Apple's GLKit which would probably be straightforward as well.

Just suggestions....

Answer (score 0):

After you create the sphere in blender you need to export in .dae format then use collada to POD convertor which is free. It will convert .dae file to .pod file. and then pod file can easily be parsed into cocos3d.